# Rewrite some code from jQuery to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm just learning, and right now rewrite my code from jQuery to Angular, have some issues, hope you can help me unriddle them.

Current html:

```
<div class='image_hold'>
  <img class='image'>
  <input type='hidden' name='image_answer' class='image_input'>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function loadGraphic() {
  $.post('generate.php', { keyword: 'image' })
    .done(function(data) {
      $('.image_input').val(data);
      $('.image').attr('src', data);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      alert('error');
    })
};
```

So, how exactly gonna have to look that bit of code in Angular?
My current attempt:

```
$scope.loadGraphic = function() {
  $http({
      method:  'POST',
      url:     'generate.php',
      data:    image,
  })
  .success(function(data) {
    if (data.errors) {
      $window.alert(error);
    } else {
      //
    }
  });
};
```

And I suppose I have to add in html something like `ng-src`... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add the returned image src as a property on `$scope` to refer to in the template, then use `ng-src` as you say. Hopefully this will serve as a starting point;

```
$scope.imageSrc = null;

$scope.loadGraphic = function() {
    $http({
        method:  'POST',
        url:     'generate.php',
        data:    image,
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.imageSrc = data;
    })
    .catch(function(errorResponse) {
        // Handle errors in here
    });
};

// Template
<!-- ... -->
<img ng-if="imageSrc" ng-src="imageSrc" class="image">
```